# How did latin "de post" become Romanian "după"?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, historical-linguistics, latin, romanian

Wouldn't the expected result be: "dopă"? I understand that the short "e" was assimilated by the long "o" from the next word, and then /o/ -> /ə/, but why o -> u ?
Or what actually happened was: "depo"/"dopo" -> "dăpă" ( or even "dîpă" /dɨpə/ later ) -> "după" due to the influence of the following labial consonant?

Comment: *de pe (dă pă)* means *from on top of*; as such, *de po(st)* needs to be distinguished from the latter.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but in the nutcase etymological dictionary by Vinereanu, full of [crazy](https://www.academia.edu/19863168/Et_22_Recenzie_Vinereanu) conclusions of the [Dacomaniac](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dacomania) flavor but often based on good premises (which makes it even more crazy, but rather informative, al least to me), I read this: "cf. it. dopo. De Mauro-Mancini (619) considers that It. *dopo* comes from "de poi”. Something similar can be said about the Rom. *după*, namely that it comes from *de* and *apo(i)*". See [apoi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apoi).